# Symfony2 array of custom objects into form fields

Tags: arrays, forms, symfony, custom-fields, guzzle

I get some data from an API inside my Symfony 2 application using Guzzle. Those data are properly mapped into my model. The model is a `Contact` object with some properties. One of those property is an array of `ContactMethod` done like this

```
/**
 * @SerializedName("methods")
 * @Type("array<My\Bundle\Model\ContactMethod>")
 */
private $methods;
```

The `ContactMethod` object has just two properties: `type` and `value`

```
class ContactMethod {

/**
 * @SerializedName("type")
 * @Type("string")
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @SerializedName("value")
 * @Type("string")
 */
private $value;

... setters and getters ...
```

I've created a `ContactType` with its `buildForm` function in order to display all the property of `Contact` in a form. But when it comes to display the `methods` property I would like to have a `TextInput` for each of the `ContactMethod` and that input should take the `type` as label and the `value` as value.

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options = array())
{
    $builder
        ->add(...all the other simple fields...)
        ->add(...what shall I add here ? )
```

I also need this to work in the opposite way: when all the text inputs are filled and submitted, the fields has to be packed together into an array of `ContactMethod` so I can reserialize and send back the data to the API.

I've tried to play around with custom form types and also Data Transformers but I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your Contact object is mapped onto one ContactType, so just add a property `methods` and its type (e.g.) `"method_list"` if it's declared as a service or just `new MethodListType()`.

The list is dynamic, so you have to write your own buildView method for the new Type.